# Animate Margin values between states in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, blend

I'm trying to familiarize myself with WPF for an upcoming project. I'm having problem animating margins between states. Using Blend I've obtained the following sample XAML. If I trigger the state "Large" from codebehind, the rectangle suddenly expands after 1 second, instead of "easing" into the expansion, which is the desired effect.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:1"/>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="Large">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                        <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="64,135,47,191"/>
                    </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Margin="428,135,47,191" Stroke="Black"/>
</Grid>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is because you only have one keyframe set to 0 in your animation.

try this :

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">

            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <!--Take one second to transition to the Large state.-->
                <VisualTransition To="Large" GeneratedDuration="0:0:1"/>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>

            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />

            <!--Change the Margin to "64,135,47,191" when the states gets to "Large"-->
            <VisualState x:Name="Large">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" To="64,135,47,191" />
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Margin="428,135,47,191" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Stroke="Black"/>
</Grid>
```

**edit:** I was not very pleased with my first shot, so here is a better way of doing this.

Comment: Hm, well the good news is that it kinda works. The bad news is that it kinda doesn't. See, what happens is the following. The rectangle wait for 1 second, then expands to full, then contracts. Fine, if I reverse the keyframes - I and up in the state that I want to be, but there's still a 1 second delay from GeneratedDuration. I am confused....

Comment: ah yes sorry I put the values backward, I edited the answer with the right order/values

Comment: Well, thank you for your solution. That 1 second delay thing is annoying, but it's not important for my solution, so I'll mark you as accepted answer. Thanks again.

Comment: thanks, I tried an other (better) way to do this, following the guidelines for the management of visualStateGroups. Hope it works better for you

Comment: Aha! I'll make sure to check it out! Thanks again!